# Website shows up fine in Atom. Doesn't work in any browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website that is currently undergoing development.

For some reason, certain divs do not want to accept their position on the website after the site is placed in production (live).

This has happened to me with the "Follow Us" tab at the bottom among other divs.

However what is really bothering me now is that the content section of this site: http://dockmann.com/projects.html should be more uniform.

[image: This is how the website looks like right now]

[image: This is what it should look like.]

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.handler').click(function() {
     var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
     if (clicks) {
       $('.container').css("top", "447px");
       $('.nBar').css("height", "300px");
       $('.nav').css("height","298px");
       $('.navigation').css("display","flex");  // odd clicks
     } else {
       $('.container').css("top", "147px");
       $('.nBar').css("height", "0px");
       $('.nav').css("height","0px");
       $('.navigation').css("display","none");  // even clicks
     }
     $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
   });
   $('.popup1').click(function(){
     var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
     if (clicks) {
       $('.popup1').animate({bottom:-50});
     } else {
       $('.popup1').animate({bottom:-77});
     }
     $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
   });
   $('.gray1').click(function(){
     alert('Attention, you are now leaving Dockmann.com; we are no longer responsible for any 3rd party content after you leave out site.')
   });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.topWrapper{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  z-index:10;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px black;
}
.header{
  /*border: 1px solid rgb(0,0,0);*/
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height:75px;
  position: relative;
  top:0px;
}
/*#title{
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  font-size: 50px;
}*/
.titleTwo{
height:60px;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
}
#contactBox{
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  top:20px;
  width:100px;
  height:40px;
  background-color: rgb(239,172,166);
  color: rgb(80,100,119);
  transition: 0.25s;

}
#contactBox:hover{
  background-color: rgb(80,100,119);
  color: rgb(239,172,166);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 25px rgb(239,172,166);
}
/*CONTACT US BUTTON = FTEXT*/
.fText{
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.nav{
  height:50px;
  width:100%;
  border: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
  background-color: white;
}
.nBar{
  display: flex;
}
li {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 15px 40px 10px 40px;
}
#home{
  height:26px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  color: rgb(80,100,119);
  transition: 0.10s;
}
#bio{
  height:26px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  color: rgb(80,100,119);
  transition: 0.10s;

}
#projects{
  height:26px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  color: rgb(80,100,119);
  transition: 0.10s;

}
#services{
  height:26px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  color: rgb(80,100,119);
  transition: 0.10s;

}
#contact{
  height:26px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
  color: rgb(80,100,119);
  transition: 0.10s;

}

#home:hover{
  background-color: rgb(80,100,119);
  color:rgb(239,172,166);
  /*transition: 0.25s;*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(239,172,166);
}
#bio:hover{
  /*background-color: black;*/
  background-color: rgb(80,100,119);
  color:rgb(239,172,166);
  /*transition: 0.25s;*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(239,172,166);
}
#projects:hover{
  background-color: rgb(80,100,119);
  color:rgb(239,172,166);
  /*transition: 0.25s;*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(239,172,166);
}
#services:hover{
  background-color: rgb(80,100,119);
  color:rgb(239,172,166);
  /*transition: 0.25s;*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(239,172,166);
}
#contact:hover{
  background-color: rgb(80,100,119);
  color:rgb(239,172,166);
  /*transition: 0.25s;*/
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(239,172,166);
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:black;
}

/*---------------------------------------body starts here*/
.container{
position:absolute;
top:127px;
width:100%;
z-index:1;
}
.content{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 960px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/*here the project grid starts*/
.prj1link{
  width: 50%;
  height:250px;
  order:0;
  background-image: url('https://s5.postimg.org/5100sghp3/prj1.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: top;
  z-index: 98;
}
/*gray1 is the opaque color on the div*/
.gray1{
  background-color: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity: 0.4;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.gray1:hover{
  color:red;
}
.window1{
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 100;
  height:10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height:65px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  order:4;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
}
.legal{
  padding-top: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.legalText{
  color:rgb(200,200,200);
}
.legalText:hover{
  color:rgb(239,172,166);
}
.handler{
  width: 100%;
  height:50px;
  background-color: rgb(80,100,119);
  color:rgb(239,172,166);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 0 0 42px;
  font-size: 30px;
  display:none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.popup1{
  background-color: rgb(80,100,119);
  color:rgb(239,172,166);
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:-77px;
  right:10;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
.popupT{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bolder;
  font-size: 20px;
}
.fbook{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  right:70px;
  height:25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: white;
}
.twitter{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  right:37px;
  height:25px;
  width: 25px;
}
.insta{
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom:50px;
  right:5px;
}
.popup1:hover{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgb(239,172,166);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="Dockmann creates websites and web apps that are light and responsive">
  <meta name="keywords" content="HTML,CSS,JavaScript">
  <meta name="author" content="Dockmann Corp">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styleProjects.css" />
  <link rel="icon" href="images/faviconR.png" type="image/x-icon" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptProjects.js"></script>
  <title>dockmann</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="topWrapper">
    <div class="header">
      <!-- <h1 id="title">DOCKMANN</h1> -->
      <a href="http://www.dockmann.com"><img class="titleTwo" src="css/images/DockmannH.svg" /></a>
      <a href="mailto:info@dockmann.com"><div id="contactBox">
        <p class="fText">
          Contact Us!
          </p>
      </div>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="nBar">
        <!--inserted .navigation because it will help
        differentiate the nav bar links when I add
         other "<a> links" along the page -->
        <a class="navigation" href="http://dockmann.com"><li id="home">
          HOME
        </li></a>
        <a class="navigation" href="bio.html"><li id="bio">
          BIO
        </li></a>
        <a class="navigation" href="projects.html"><li id="projects">
          PROJECTS
        </li></a>
        <a class="navigation" href="services.html"><li id="services">
          SERVICES
        </li></a>
        <a class="navigation" href="contact.html"><li id="contact">
          CONTACT
        </li>
        </a>
      </ul>
      <div class="handler">
        Menu
        <img class="menuIcon" src="css/images/menu1R.svg" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bodyWrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        <a class="prj1link" href="http://www.miamitheory.com"><div class="prj1">
          <div class="gray1">
            <!-- window 1 is designed to display text- so on and so forth -->
            <div class="window1">
              <p class="windowt1">
              THE MIAMI THEORY</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div></a>
        <div class="footer">
        <!-- add link here to disclaimer page -->
        <p class="legal">
          <a class="legalText" href="disclaimer.html">LEGAL</a>
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="popup1">
      <p class="popupT">
        Follow us!
      </p>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/dockmann2016/"><img class="fbook" src="css/images/facebook2.svg" /></a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/dockmann2016"><img class="twitter" src="css/images/twitter1.svg" /></a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/dockmann_com/"><img class="insta" src="css/images/instagram3.svg" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
    (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
    m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-82779137-1', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should solve this problem by "debugging it"--stripping out one element at a time, changing one thing a ttime--until you pin down the issue. What you have posted is far too much code for anyone here to go through and find the problem.

Comment: @torazaburo fair enough. I will try that. I just needed to rule out anything blatantly obvious before I dismantled the code. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This has happened to me with the "Follow Us" tab at the bottom among other divs.

The "follow us" button is at the bottom of the page because it is `position: fixed; bottom: -77px;`

> However what is really bothering me now is that the content section of this site: http://dockmann.com/projects.html should be more uniform.

What do you mean by "be more uniform" exactly? If you want "the miami theory" to be in the middle of that area with the background, add `height: 100%;` to `.prj1`. Since it's direct descendent, `.gray1` has `height: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;` the only child of `.gray1`, which is `.window1` (and holds the text "the miami theory"), will be centered horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very clear on my initial question. I meant to say that the follow us tab at the bottom should have been placed to the bottom right of the viewport as the code states.

Answer (score 1):

You lost a "px" after "right:10".

```
.popup1{
  background-color: rgb(80,100,119);
  color:rgb(239,172,166);
  height:100px;
  width: 100px;
  position:fixed;
  bottom:-77px;
  right:10px;
  z-index: 10;
  border-radius: 10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-flow: row;
  align-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Comment: This answer is also correct.